What may be causing a D5000 shutter release button error?
My old Nikon D5000 is having a shutter release button error when I attach the lens. When I remove the lens my camera can take picture even in continuous mode. Should I buy new lens or repair the camera? Can the lens affect the shutter release button?

Is there an actual error code on the lop screen; FEE or F–– ?

What specific lens? (Please include full lens name, e.g. AF-S Nikkor 50mm f/1.4)

What lens? If it is one of the newer AF-P lenses, it isn't compatible with your older D5000. In the D5xxx series, the first body compatible with Nikon's AF-P lenses is the D5200.
